# How jquery can call a function in the 'end' of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want understand how jquery can accomplish this:

```
$('.test').css().otherThing...... etc
```

I'm trying to do with prototype:

```
var myPrototype = function () {};

myPrototype.prototype.console1 = function() {
 console.log('1');
};


myPrototype.prototype.console2 = function() {
 console.log('2');
};

var obj = new myPrototype();

obj.console1().console2();
```

but.. of course didn't work.. this is possible with prototype?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To allow this **chaining**, you have to return `this` in your functions:

```
myPrototype.prototype.console1 = function() {
 console.log('1');
 return this;
};


myPrototype.prototype.console2 = function() {
 console.log('2');
 return this;
};
```

Comment: interesting.. can i make the chaining optional?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Optional ? How so ? You can always not use it.

Comment: i'm going to accept your answer in 10.. (you answered to fast.)

Comment: ops... sorry hahahaha